# Where does demo code usually go when installed with package manager.

Tags: yum

In this particular example I am trying to get the CGAL Library demo code wich is availble from the Fedora package manager `yum`:

```
CGAL-demos-source.x86_64 : Examples and demos of CGAL algorithms
CGAL-devel.i686 : Development files and tools for CGAL applications
```

I know the development packages end up in `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib64`.
**I want to look at the demo source, where does this usually end up?**

Answer (score 4):

If the package isn't installed you can also use `repoquery` to look into a uninstalled package directly from the YUM repository.

#### Example

```
$ repoquery -ql CGAL-demos-source | grep examples | head
/usr/share/CGAL/examples
/usr/share/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree
/usr/share/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_custom_example.cpp
/usr/share/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_custom_indexed_triangle_set_array_example.cpp
/usr/share/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_custom_indexed_triangle_set_example.cpp
/usr/share/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_custom_triangle_soup_example.cpp
/usr/share/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_face_graph_triangle_example.cpp
/usr/share/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_halfedge_graph_edge_example.cpp
/usr/share/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_insertion_example.cpp
/usr/share/CGAL/examples/AABB_tree/AABB_polyhedron_edge_example.cpp
```

In the above output you can see that the code is under this directory:

```
/usr/share/CGAL/examples
```

#### What package?

If you're unsure what package might have the demo files in it, you can use `repoquery` like so find that out too.

```
$ repoquery -q CGAL*
CGAL-0:4.3-1.fc20.i686
CGAL-0:4.3-1.fc20.x86_64
CGAL-demos-source-0:4.3-1.fc20.x86_64
CGAL-devel-0:4.3-1.fc20.i686
CGAL-devel-0:4.3-1.fc20.x86_64
```

Here's all the packages that match the pattern "CGAL*". Based on this it's likely the demo files are inside this package: `CGAL-demos-source-0:4.3-1.fc20.x86_64`.

If you want that package installed:

```
$ sudo yum install CGAL-demos-source
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `rpm -ql CGAL-demos-source` gives you some food for thought.

Comment: Doesnt work. perhaps the usage is incorrect?

Comment: @Ben, you are right - fixed. A Del key misbehavin'...